Why do Lisp style guides recommend the specific numbers of semicolons for comment in several cases?
I read in the style guide of Elisp and of Common Lisp to use specific numbers of semicolons in various cases, in short this:

single semicolons for comments at the ends of code lines
double semicolons for comments on their own lines
triple semicolons for documentation comments
quadruple semicolons for code headers and footers

Specifically, why are double semicolons supposed to be used in comments on their own lines? Why did someone decide to do it that way? It seems that double semicolons do not add any information because it is obvious that the comments are on their own lines, and I don't see any other purpose for them. I prefer using single semicolons there and decrease the number of semicolons in the following cases (so two for documentation).

I'm not sure that there is a deep reason for this, but it has been a convention for a long time. I don't like single-semicolon comments alone on a line because I don't think that they stand out enough. Note that some editors will indent single-semicolon comments to the "comment column" even if they are on lines by themselves, so anyone else working with your code may have to contend with that even if your editor doesn't do this. It really isn't worth nitpicking over such things; when in Rome....

I do not know the history, or even if the history is completely known.  I have used Lisps which did not have ; as a comment character (rather %) but I do not now remember whether they had the same convention.
But what matters is that it is a convention: if you follow the convention other people will be able to read your code, and other people's editors will be able to handle your code.  Using some different convention for comments, just as using a different convention for indentation, is a way of making programs you write less usable by other people.  If you're the only person who will ever look at them, do what you will, of course.
The current convention has some noticeable advantages, however.
(defun foo (x)
  ;; conventional comment saying what FOO does
  (let ((d (ccm x)))                    ;note things about d here but
                                        ;this note is quite long
    ;; This comment does not continue from the previous one, but
    ;; rather describes some things about this part of the code.
;;; This is all broken
;;;     (when (< d *the-mass*)
;;;       (let* ((r (radiation-case-size d)))
;;;         (commission (manufacture-radiation-case r) d r)))
     d))

As you can see, the distinction between a trailing comment which happens to span two lines and the following interline comment matters here.  And the intentioanlly-ugly three-colon comments within the function indicate immediately that something odd is going on, and in particular that the function has parts of itself commented out.
Similarly the use of four semicolons for section headers is typographicaly useful: it helps people read long toplevel comments which are divided into sections, with titles.

Such conventions also mean that the text editor can recognise the different cases, and behave appropriately -- for instance it can automatically change the way it indents/fills single- and double-colon comments, and section headers can be used for outlining.

I was just about to add the same as @phils. At least Emacs will indent comments and code according to that convention. I think they could also be used in a regex to feed to outline-mode in Emacs for folding sections of file based on the content. By the way, great insight about conventions and coding by you ignis.
